# Collection.shuffle not working - GWT

Tags: java, collections, shuffle

Using the `import java.util.Collections;` like I should be.  Not the GWT one.  Have the class with the error in the shared folder for a GWT project.

#### code is of this structure:

```
List<String []> qaList;
qaList = new ArrayList<String[]>();

qaList.add("12345 main st", "tomah");
qaList.add("124 main st", "lacrosse");
qaList.add("123 main", "yeeehahaaa");

Collections.shuffle(qaList);
```

#### Gives me this error:

> [ERROR] [_012cfaexam] - Line 109: The method `shuffle(List<String[]>)` is undefined for the >type Collections

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoted from [GWT's JRE Emulation Reference](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation):

> Google Web Toolkit includes a library that emulates a subset of the Java runtime library. The list below shows the set of JRE packages, types and methods that GWT can translate automatically. Note that in some cases, only a subset of methods is supported for a given type.

Specifically, if you look at `Collections` in the [Package java.util](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation#Package_java_util), you will see that it does not contain the `shuffle()` method.

Comment: I am a bit confused though since I am not calling it from 'within' GWT.  I have it in the shared folder for a GWT project on appengine.  I thought this folder was executed on the server.  It must not be.  ANyways, thanks, i will have to read up more on that and probably put it on the server folder and make an async call to get the data.

Comment: @user1318747 the 'shared' package can be called on both the client and server. the 'server' package is for only the server.

Answer (score 4):

There is another one way to solve this bug:

```
Random random = new Random(qaList.size());  

for(int index = 0; index < qaList.size(); index += 1) {  
    Collections.swap(qaList, index, index + random.nextInt(qaList.size() - index));  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what matsev has already said:

If your code is GPL, you can just copy SUNs implementation:

```
public static void shuffle(List<?> list, Random rnd) {
    int size = list.size();
    if (size < SHUFFLE_THRESHOLD || list instanceof RandomAccess) {
        for (int i=size; i>1; i--)
            swap(list, i-1, rnd.nextInt(i));
    } else {
        Object arr[] = list.toArray();

        // Shuffle array
        for (int i=size; i>1; i--)
            swap(arr, i-1, rnd.nextInt(i));

        // Dump array back into list
        ListIterator it = list.listIterator();
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            it.next();
            it.set(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

It is basically [Fisher Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) with some optimizations in case the list isn't random access.